# Clean method to call interface functions with a vector of objects

Tags: c++, oop, function-pointers

I have a vector of tasks implementing the same interface.  I have a state machine object that can have multiple tasks, and I have a whole bunch of events.  If a particular event is called, I would like the event to call a function to 'ProcessTasks' in which ProcessTasks takes the particular interface function that needs to be called, and calls that function for every task.  I would like to avoid having a giant case statement or repeating the for loop iteration in every event function, but I'm not sure how to.  Is there a construct/approach that allows me to do this, or is the case statement approach the best method, or the toss the loop in each function best?

Thanks : )

Sample Example ( a single state class in my state patterned sm ):

```
State_e StateIdle::EVENT_REQUEST_STOP_()
{
    ProcessTasks( HandleStopFn );
    return STATE_STOPPED;
}

// -- more events

/* desired solution allows me to have to implement
   the loop only once, but be able to call any of
   the functions in the interface, for any number of events */

    for( vector<TaskPtr>::iterator it = m_tasks.begin(); it != m_tasks.end(); ++it )
    {
        it->HandlerFunction()
    }
```

---

//TaskPtr is boost auto ptr and implements this shortened interface

```
class Task
{
    void HandleActiveFn() = 0;
    void HandleStopFn() = 0;
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provide a `private` member function in `StateIdle` that accepts a `Task` member function pointer and use `std::for_each` to invoke the member function on each of the `Task` instances:

```
void _invoker(void (Task::*fun)())
{
    std::for_each(m_tasks.begin(),
                  m_tasks.end(),
                  [&](TaskPtr a_t) { (a_t->*fun)(); });
}
```

See demo http://ideone.com/A4c5U .

If you wanted to avoid a `switch` you could construct a function table using a `std::map`:

```
std::map<std::string, void (Task::*)()> function_table;
function_table["ACTIVE"] = &Task::HandleActiveFn;
function_table["STOP"]   = &Task::HandleStopFn;

void _invoker(const std::string& a_name)
{
    auto function_entry = function_table.find(a_name);
    if (function_table.end() != function_entry)
    {
        std::for_each(m_tasks.begin(),
                      m_tasks.end(),
                      [&](TaskPtr a_t)
                      {
                          (a_t->*(function_entry->second))(); 
                      });
    }
}
```

And to call:

```
_invoker("STOP");
_invoker("ACTIVE");
```

which you may prefer to:

```
_invoker(&Task::HandleStopFn);
_invoker(&Task::HandleActiveFn);
```

Answer (score 2):

You could bind the functions to an `std::function`, then loop over the vector (or use `std::for_each`) calling the function and passing a pointer to each element as first parameter. For example, this is how you can bind the member functions and call them on an instance of a type:

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

struct IFoo 
{
  virtual void foo1() const = 0;
  virtual void foo2() const = 0;
};

struct Foo : public IFoo
{

  virtual void foo1() const {
    std::cout << "Foo::foo1\n";
  }
  virtual void foo2() const {
    std::cout << "Foo::foo2\n";
  }
};

int main() {

  std::function <void(IFoo*)> f1 = &IFoo::foo1;
  std::function <void(IFoo*)> f2 = &IFoo::foo2;

  std::vector<IFoo*> foos{new Foo(), new Foo(), new Foo()};

  std::for_each(foos.begin(), foos.end(), f1);

  std::for_each(foos.begin(), foos.end(), f2);

}
```

If you are storing elements by value, instead of pointers, you could use [std::mem_fn](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/mem_fn):

```
auto f1 = std::mem_fn(&Foo::foo1);
auto f2 = std::mem_fn(&Foo::foo2);

std::list<Foo> foos = ....;

std::for_each(foos2.begin(), foos2.end(), f1);
```

Comment: each item in the vector needs to call a member function of the interface, it looks like the for_each construct has a function pointer and passes each item in the vector through it, so I don't think it solved the problem

Comment: @pyInTheSky which interface? Are you concerned that polymorphism might not work?

Comment: @pyInTheSky I extended my example to work with polymorphic types, although from your edits I see this is not required.

Comment: hmjd's link is exactly what I had, sorry I didn't understand how the for_each needed to go, but I think his example code was exceptional for explaining what I needed to do.

Comment: @pyInTheSky No worries. Both examples achieve more or less the same. I find `std::function` more readable so I tend to favour it over function pointers.